# Where can I get standard iOS icon collection in PDF format?

Tags: data-request, images, pdf

PDF is the newly supported format on iOS 8, in order to avoid the hassle of resizing icons for different device resolutions. Where I can get free / standard icon collection? For example, `Go back`, `Share`, `Toggle`, `Resize`, `Send`, `Contacts` buttons?

Comment: regardless of ios specifics, i highly recommend not using pdf. svg is not only superior, it is the future

Comment: Xcode accept only PDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149785/xcode-6-allows-vector-image-assets-any-idea-how-to-use-them

Comment: wow. boo ios. i'd love to hear apple's justification for this.

Comment: SVG to PDF (other formats) can be easily implemented - http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools#Convert_to.2Ffrom_SVG

Answer (score 6):

Using a [Advanced Google Image Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search), you can search based on file type ([SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), not PDF) and also usage rights. If you want a common theme for all buttons, then you can use this tool to find single websites that host similarly designed images that meet your criteria.

[Here is an example](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=resize+icon&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=ift:svg&gws_rd=ssl#q=resize+button&as_st=y&tbs=ift:svg&tbm=isch&tbas=0) of the Resize Buttons with SVG. You'll have to filter by license for your use.

[image]

---

To find PDF files, you can't use the Image Search tool but you can use [Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search), and specify PDF as the file type.

---

To create or edit vector files (i.e. PDF or SVG), there is a very professional open source program called [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (similar functionality to Adobe Illustrator). With this tool, you can also easily make your own buttons in vector format. You can also easily convert SVG to PDF, using tools described [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools#Convert_to.2Ffrom_SVG).