# Where can I get the standard iOS 8 bar icons in a vector graphics format?

Tags: data-request, images

I need this images piece by piece in vector graphics format. Any idea how to get them?

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/icon_family_2x.png

Comment: Did you see this? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3851/1511

Comment: I know that there is (are?) data that are also images ... but icons are obviously a creative work, and not just in the 'creatively calibrated data' or 'creatively visualized data' realm.  I'm not aware of an iOS developer specific stack exchange site, but you might have luck asking on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

[Austin Andrews](http://templarian.com/) has built (and collated from elsewhere, when licensing permits) a collection of icons that follow the [material design](http://materialdesignicons.com/). These are also available from [his Github repository in a variety of formats, including SVG](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign/).

To use the actual Apple glyphs within an iOS app, then you can refer to [the documentation for UIBarButtonSystemItem in UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem)

Comment: quite promising selection but not the iOS 8 one

Comment: Some appeared to be there "as is", but I see no reason why you couldn't either use the [suggest](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign/issues) option, or derive/build your own that you contribute to the repo.